# Adder circuit yields large errors on real hardware

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I was playing with qiskit's [adder example](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/introduction/the-atoms-of-computation#the-15-176) using the following code

```
for q3210 in ['0000', '0010', '0001', '0011']:
   qc = QuantumCircuit(4, 2)
   qc.initialize(q3210, qc.qubits)
   qc.cx(1,2)
   qc.cx(0,2)
   qc.ccx(0,1,3)
   qc.measure([2,3], [0,1])

   transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, device)
   job = device.run(transpiled_qc)
   result = job.result()
   print(q3210, "  :  ",result.get_counts())
```

The simulator yields the correct results. Running the same circuit on IBM's Lima or Nairobi setups, yields the following:

```
0000   :   {'00': 3663, '01': 193, '10': 129, '11': 15}
0010   :   {'00': 1129, '01': 2464, '10': 135, '11': 272}
0001   :   {'00': 334, '01': 3426, '10': 49, '11': 191}
0011   :   {'00': 620, '01': 83, '10': 3185, '11': 112}
```

Some errors are to be expected, I am aware of that.
But is it normal to get in say, for the '0010' state, a correct answer in only 62% of the experiments?
Why does the '0001' state yield much lower errors compared to the above '0010'state?

I also tried different gate orders, i.e. placing the Toffoli before the CNOT gates. Yet, the largest errors stay with the '0010' state.

What am I overlooking here or how to explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machines are, indeed very noisy at the moment. What you could do is to spend more time optimizing the circuit before submitting. Here, the result of your code in `ibmq_lima` with `transpiled_qc = transpile(qc, device, optimization_level=3)`:

```
0000   :   {'00': 3679, '01': 107, '10': 138, '11': 76}
0010   :   {'00': 380, '01': 3421, '10': 50, '11': 149}
0001   :   {'00': 510, '01': 3233, '10': 59, '11': 198}
0011   :   {'00': 591, '01': 107, '10': 3163, '11': 139}
```

It seems to me that the result is substantially better. It could be that your circuit is allocated in a particular noisy part of the device. The parameter `optimization_level=3` is "noise-aware" meaning that considers the calibration information as part of the transpilation process.

Comment: This is indeed an improvement. As the docs are rather unspecific on this part: Is there any information or notion available regarding what the optimization levels specifically do?